# Is it possible to target string "--" with regex?

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

is it possible to target string after "--" in URL to redirect to another page?

Say we have these two URLs:

```
1. www.domain.com/some/some2/some3/my-page.html
2. www.domain.com/some/some2/some3/my-page--woohoo.html
```

First one just displays content of my-page.html.

What I need is to redirect second URL to

```
www.domain.com/index.php?pagename=$matches[4]&var=$string
```

so in this case it would be:

```
www.domain.com/index.php?pagename=my-page&var=woohoo
```

Any idea if it is possible?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Anything is possible. What have you tried?

Comment: @Allendar Not anything ... You cannot be *God* `;-)`

Comment: I'm just having 1000's of urls looking like /some/some2/my-page.html and need to add subpage for many of em. Having trailing slash it would be easy but with .html at the end it is more complicated, therefore double slash hopefully will make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I think you are looking for something like this:

Pattern:

```
^(.*?)\/.*\/([a-zA-Z-]+)--(.*)\..*$
```

- `^` assert position at start of the string
- `(.*?)` matches any character (except newline) as a capturing group
- `\/` matches the character / literally
- `[a-zA-Z-]+` match a single character between mentioned list `a-z, A-Z, -`
- `--` matches the characters -- literally
- `$` assert position at end of the string

Substitution:

```
$1/index.php?pagename=$2&var=$3
```

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/rI8cZ4/2)

---

As you've  used `apache` tag for your question, this can help:

```
#With mod_rewrite
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule  "(.*?)\/.*\/([a-zA-Z-]+)--(.*)\..*$"  "$1/index.php?pagename=$2&var=$3"  [R,L]

#With RedirectMatch
RedirectMatch "(.*?)\/.*\/([a-zA-Z-]+)--(.*)\..*$" "$1/index.php?pagename=$2&var=$3"
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try and report back!

Comment: It works fine in htaccess but when I try to insert it via PHP (add_rewrite_rule('^(.*?)\/.*\/.*\/([a-zA-Z-]+)--woohoo\.html$', 'index.php?&pagename=$matches[2]', 'top');), I'm not able to make it work (calling www.domain.com/some/some2/my-page--woohoo.html returns http 404). Weird is that when i change rule to add_rewrite_rule('^(.*?)\/.*\/.*\/([a-zA-Z-]+)--woohoo\.html$', 'index.php?&pagename=my-page', 'top'); it works correctly. Don't you know why?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly are you looking for, but maybe [this](https://3v4l.org/IJJYR) help

Comment: I created another question as my actual problem is beyond this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35846891/why-matches2-does-not-return-anything-in-rewrite-rule

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following rule in server.config or htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^/]+)--([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?pagename=%1&var=%2 [NC,L,R]
```

This will redirect :

- /some/some1/some2/my-page--woohoo.html

to

- /index.php?pagename=my-page&var=woohoo

Comment: what if page have name like "my-another-page--woohoo.html" - will it work then?

Comment: @Pupik I edited the cond pattern. it should work for multiple **-**  .

Comment: unfortunatelly this didn't work. Even in regex101.com it shows errors... Don't know why. But thanks anyway!

Comment: @Pupik not sure why it didnt work for you, I tested it twice on my apache server it works fine for the urls.

Comment: I used  shorter version of regex in the cond pattern, may be it is the reason of error on regex101 ,but the regex is correct and it matches all the urls you mentioned in this post.